# Pip install fails with SSLCertVerificationError [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: ssl, pip

When installing any package with pip it fails with the error:

```
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': [...]
```

The host is a Ubuntu:22.04 container on a MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

I tried

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package>
```

then reseted Docker to factory defaults and reinstalled it, but no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is related with my ISP provider (Vadafone) that has a protection service called SecureNet that generates the error.

Deactivating the SecureNet service solved the issue.

More info: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10963